# Get Anyhashable type of data?

Tags: swift

### How to get userid using for loop from the Anyhashable type of data?

```
    //This is the data and I want to get all of the userid from this data

▿ some : 6 elements
    ▿ 0 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("company_name")
        - value : "company_name"
      - value : Company 2549
    ▿ 1 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("contact_unique_id")
        - value : "contact_unique_id"
      - value : 230679
    ▿ 2 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("Client_Phone")
        - value : "Client_Phone"
      - value : 999999
    ▿ 3 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("userid")
        - value : "userid"
      - value : 7295
    ▿ 4 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("full_name")
        - value : "full_name"
      - value : A. B. M
    ▿ 5 : 2 elements
      ▿ key : AnyHashable("email_address")
        - value : "email_address"
      - value : wwsum.mar.com

 if Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectContacts.count > 0 {
                let contactDictionary = Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectContacts[0] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
                let contactName       = contactDictionary!["full_name"] as! String

            let toBeDisplayedText = Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectContacts.count > 1 ? "\(contactName) + \(Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectContacts.count - 1) more" : contactName                self.btnSelectContact.setTitle(toBeDisplayedText  , for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.btnSelectContact.setTitleColor(UIColor.black , for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
            else {
            self.btnSelectContact.setTitle("Tap to Select Contact(s)", for: UIControlState.normal)
            self.btnSelectContact.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray , for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        if Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectAssignees.count > 0   {
            let contactDictionary = Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectAssignees[0] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
```

//I am try to get userid from this code

```
            let contactName       = contactDictionary!["full_name"] as! String
                           if let users = contactDictionary as? [String : Any]   {
                            print(users)
                            for user in users  {
                                print(user)

                                       }
                                       }
```

Comment: There is probably a minus mark for multiple reasons. 1) What is the overall type of data? 2) Where is your code that shows how you got this set of data? 3) Do you think there is enough information from you to get community help? I'd say maybe, but it could be incredibly difficult. You should make it as easy as possible using a small, concise, and clear example as you possibly can.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Begging for the rules to be bent just for you is likely to get you more downvotes, not fewer. Find out [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `if-let` to fetch the required value from `contactDictionary`, i.e.

```
if let userId = contactDictionary?["userid"] as? String {
    //use userId here...
}
```

Comment: how I can I use for loop to store all user id

Comment: For that you need to add the structure of contactDictionary from where you want to fetch the userIds.

Comment: The details you added are not clear enough. From the question it seems you want to fetch a single userId. Where does multiple userIds exist?

Comment: There are multiple user id please give me the solution

Comment: No-one will be able to help until you give us the structure from where multiple userId needs to be fetched.