# How to get Data from AnyHashable type of Dictionary?

Tags: swift

### how to get all userid from this type of dictionary

```
 Optional([AnyHashable("contact_unique_id"): 235567, AnyHashable("full_name"): A. Erd insonaa, AnyHashable("userid"): 15019, AnyHashable("company_name"): pord, Derek & Co., mmd (Asset Management), AnyHashable("Client_Phone"): +61 434367243434331676213266661, AnyHashable("email_address"): rana.kumari@ting.com])


Optional([AnyHashable("contact_unique_id"): 2353223567, AnyHashable("full_name"): A. Edward radadoi, AnyHashable("userid"): 15019, AnyHashable("company_name"): Chod, Gameal & Co., Tom (Asset Management), AnyHashable("Client_Phone"): +61 6778989876213266661, AnyHashable("email_address"): ramul@rose.com])
```

### I have Tried the following Code

```
       let contactDictionary = Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectAssignees[0] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
                print(contactDictionary)
            let contactName  = contactDictionary!["full_name"] as! String
                  print(contactName)
        for id in contactDictionary! {
                print(id["userid"]) as! Int
            }
```

### But it give this type of error

Value of tuple type '(key: AnyHashable, value: Any)' has no member 'subscript'

Comment: Don't ask the same question from different accounts.

Comment: sorry I never ask this question from different accounts

Comment: Yes you did. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58687084/get-anyhashable-type-of-data/58687848#58687848

Answer (score 0):

```
let contactDictionary = Utils.getSharedManagerObject().arraySelectAssignees[0] as? [String : Any]
print(contactDictionary)
let contactName  = contactDictionary!["full_name"] as! String
print(contactName)
for id in contactDictionary! {
    print(id["userid"]) as! Int
}
```

contactDictionary is not an array type, it's simple key-value, so can't have subscript.

If you wish to use for loop, you can get the value of userID using

```
for id in contactDictionary {
    if id.key == "userid" {
        print(id.value)
        break
    }
}
```

More simple approach would be to directly get the value using

```
print(contactDictionary!["userid"] as! Int)
```

Comment: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnyHashable' and 'String'

Comment: @rahulmishra I have edited the response, please check. Changing [AnyHashable: Any] to [String: Any] will work